# How to create custom dialog box with two button in android?

Tags: android, customdialog

How to generate custom dialog box in android like this,
[image]

I want just like this.
How to generate it. please give me suggestion.

i have used below code for dialog box, what is the problem in my code?
I have not identify it. please share me any Idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_quit_learning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_white"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/thirty_dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten_dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_quit_learning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:text="Quit LEarning?"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twenty_sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_quit_learning"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/twenty_dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="You are 400pts. away from \n unlocking rewards. Quit LEarning?"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Video" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please share me any Idea.
Thanks.

Comment: You can get your answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android

Comment: Just create a class how extend `AlertDIalog.Builder` and inflate your layout, then add him to the class by `setVIew(yourView)`

Comment: But Cancel and Video Game button which is display middle in main layout.Please see image of dialogbox

Answer (score 18):

Simple, 1st need to create an **newcustom_layout.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Quit Earning?"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="You are 400pts. away from \n unlocking rewards. quit Earning?"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/frmNo"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@android:color/transparent"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/fab2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:text="No"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/frmOk"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@android:color/transparent"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/fab1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then, in **java file** (in activity) paste this code

```
 public class ViewDialog {

    public void showDialog(Activity activity) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.newcustom_layout);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        FrameLayout mDialogNo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.frmNo);
        mDialogNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cancel" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        FrameLayout mDialogOk = dialog.findViewById(R.id.frmOk);
        mDialogOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Okay" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

**Finally** you can call it wherever you want.

```
    ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
    alert.showDialog(CustomDialogActivity.this);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Inside your dailog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_quit_learning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_white"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/thirty_dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten_dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_quit_learning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:text="Quit LEarning?"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twenty_sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_quit_learning"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/twenty_dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="You are 400pts. away from \n unlocking rewards. Quit LEarning?"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

open dimens.xml and add code mentioned below

```
<dimen name="thirty_dp">30dp</dimen>
<dimen name="ten_dp">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="twenty_sp">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="twenty_dp">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="sixteen_sp">16sp</dimen>
```

open drawable and create btn_white.xml add code mentioned blow

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="2dp"></corners>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
</shape>
```

open mainactivity.java and add the code mentioned below

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
// Include dialog.xml file
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dailog);
dialog.show();

Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
// if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Close dialog
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

Button videoButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_video);
// if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
videoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**custom_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="#3E80B4"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Do you realy want to exit ?"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#3E80B4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_no"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="No"
        android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can change your button by using

```
   android:src=@drawable/image
```

You have to **extends Dialog** and **implements OnClickListener**

```
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
android.view.View.OnClickListener {



 public Activity c;
  public Dialog d;
  public Button yes, no;

  public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
    yes.setOnClickListener(this);
    no.setOnClickListener(this);

  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_yes:
      c.finish();
      break;
    case R.id.btn_no:
      dismiss();
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
    dismiss();
  }
}
```

**Call Dialog**

```
CustomDialogClass cdd=new CustomDialogClass(Activity.this);
cdd.show();
```

Comment: But you can see my image for dialogbox. which is display button middle of layout

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this method

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
app:cardElevation="10dp"
app:contentPadding="20dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_all"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonNormal"
    android:text="Tebrikler!"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:padding="8dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDialogCancel"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Çıkış"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_button_background"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDialogOk"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Devam"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_button_background"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

main.java

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomDialog);
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    CardView cardView = (CardView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                    dialog.setContentView(cardView);
                    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    dialog.show();
                    dialogBtnCancel();


 private void dialogBtnCancel(){
    mBtnDialogCancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDialogCancel);
    mBtnDialogOk = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDialogOk);

    mBtnDialogCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    mBtnDialogOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.